# class object passed in delegate method becomes <uninitialized> in Mac catalyst

Tags: ios, xcode, protocols, swift5, mac-catalyst

object passed in delegate method becomes uninitialized in class where protocol is implemented. but same object have valid address in class from where delegate was called. This happens only in maccatalyst same code works perfectly in iOS and iPadOS

Protocol Declaration

```
 protocol ASPatientSearchDelegate: class {
    func moveToPaitentProfileScreen(patient: ASCardEntity)
}
```

Delegate variable declaration

```
    weak var delegate: ASPatientSearchDelegate? = nil
```

Delegate calling

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let patient = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]

                self.delegate?.moveToPaitentProfileScreen(patient: patient)
}
```

Method Implementation

```
extension ASAppointmentViewController: ASPatientSearchDelegate {
        func moveToPaitentProfileScreen(patient: ASCardEntity) {
    
            guard let json = patient.details as? JSON else { return }
    }
}
```

Delegate Assigned in ASAppointmentViewController

```
   @IBAction func searchButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let searchViewController = ASPatientSearchViewController(nibName: ASPatientSearchViewController.className, bundle: nil)

        searchViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        searchViewController.modelController.delegate = self
}
```

Class Used

```
class ASCardEntity: NSObject {
    var details: Any?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was instance scope issue. I have declared ASPatientSearchViewController instance variable to class scope

Instance variable declaration

```
class ASAppointmentViewController: ASBaseViewController {
    var searchViewController: ASPatientSearchViewController?
}
```

I changed below code

```
@IBAction func searchButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let searchViewController = ASPatientSearchViewController(nibName: ASPatientSearchViewController.className, bundle: nil)

        searchViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        searchViewController.modelController.delegate = self
}
```

To

```
if self.searchViewController == nil {
        self.searchViewController = ASPatientSearchViewController(nibName: ASPatientSearchViewController.className, bundle: nil)
        
    }
    self.searchViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    self.searchViewController.modelController.delegate = self
```